# Spring Cloud Gateway with Resilience4J Circuit Breaker did not go to open state

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, resilience4j, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

While attempting to integrate Resilience4J with Spring Cloud Gateway, some features such as retry appear to be working properly, but the Circuit Breaker did not open the state although failure was counted as shown at below screenshot.

```
 @Bean
public Customizer<ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
    return factory->factory.configureDefault(id->new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
            .circuitBreakerConfig(CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                    .slidingWindowSize(5)
                    .failureRateThreshold(2)
                    .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(5)
                    .slowCallDurationThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(200))
                    .slowCallRateThreshold(50.0F)
                    .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                    .slidingWindowType(CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED)
                    .build())
            .timeLimiterConfig(TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                    .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(3000))
                    .cancelRunningFuture(true)
                    .build())

            .build());
}
```

and this is route configuration

```
 private Buildable<Route> setPredicateSpec(ApiRoute apiRoute, PredicateSpec predicateSpec) {
    BooleanSpec booleanSpec=predicateSpec.path(apiRoute.getPath());
    booleanSpec.filters(f->
    {
        f.circuitBreaker(c->{
            c.setName("DDDDDDTTTTT");
            c.addStatusCode("500");

        });

        f.fallbackHeaders(config ->{
            config.setExecutionExceptionMessageHeaderName("message-header");
            config.setExecutionExceptionTypeHeaderName("type-header");
            config.setRootCauseExceptionMessageHeaderName("root-cause-message-header");
            config.setRootCauseExceptionTypeHeaderName("root-cause-type-header");
        });
        f.filter(authenticationFilter);
        f.retry(config->{
            config.setMethods(HttpMethod.GET);
            config.setRetries(2);
            config.setBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(50),Duration.ofMillis(500),0,false);
            config.setStatuses(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        });

        f.requestRateLimiter(r->{
            r.setKeyResolver(apiKeyResolver);
            r.setRateLimiter(rateLimiter);
        });

        return f;
    });

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(apiRoute.getMethod())) {
        booleanSpec.and()
                .method(apiRoute.getMethod());
    }
    return booleanSpec.uri(apiRoute.getUri());
}
```

and

[image]

As a result, failures have been counted, but the failure rate is `-1`

Here are my properties as well.

```
  spring.cloud.gateway.filter.request-rate-limiter.deny-empty-key=false
  management.endpoint.gateway.enabled=true
  management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
  management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
  management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
  management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
  management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled= true
  management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled= true
  spring.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.enabled = true
```

as well as my dependencies

```
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
  implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.11'
  implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
  implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
  implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.2.Final'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
  runtimeOnly "io.opentelemetry.javaagent:opentelemetry-javaagent:1.18.0"
  runtimeOnly 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core'
  runtimeOnly 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
```